# Have knockout observable check for null

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I was wondering if there was a way to have knockout check to see if data is `null` before it tries to put it into an observable?

Right now I do this:

```
if (!data.Filename) {
    this.FileName = ko.observable("");
}
else {
    this.FileName = ko.observable(data.Filename);
}
```

Otherwise a null value in the data will cause the entire property not to show up. Is there a way to use extenders or something that I can add a null check to without having to do this with every property? My data has nulls in random places that I can't control and I don't want the property not to show up because one row in the dataset has a null value for that property.

Seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by: not show up? Can you show us some html with the bindings? Or maybe a working example on jsfiddle

Comment: When the data comes back from the server it has a property "Filename", when I map it to my observablearray, the "Filename" property doesn't get mapped and does not appear in whatever it is bound to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

heh

There are a number of ways to do this.  What I would do is

```
var self = this;
self.fileName = ko.observable(data.Filename);
self.fileNameComputed = ko.computed(function(){
       return self.fileName() || ""
});
```

Then, in your mark up reference the computed instead if the observable.

Comment: Please consider using pureComputed instead in your examples, unless the question is about a older version of knockout

Comment: :) I am still stuck on version 2.0, so thats what I am familiar with

Comment: This works for several reasons... most of all it is the simplest, and another because it keeps self.Filename as either null or data, which I use for a conditional...

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript there are other patterns available to do this.

The **first**, and simplest, is akin to the `??` operator in C#:

```
function ViewModel(data)  {
  data = data || {};
  this.Filename .observable(data.Filename || "");
}
```

The `||` operator will return the left operand unless it is [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/419956), then it'll fall back to the second argument. My example above will:

1. Make sure `data` itself is "at least" an empty object (where `.Filename` would be undefined);
2. Make sure that the input to `ko.observable(...)` is "at least" the empty string.

A **second** option would be to use default options. An example that utilizes jQuery to merge input data and default options:

```
var defaultData = {
  Filename: "enter-a-file" // could also be empty string of course!
};

function ViewModel(data)  {
  var dto = $.extend({}, defaultData, data);
  this.Filename = ko.observable(dto.Filename);
}
```

This will "fold" `data` into `defaultData`, and fold that result into an empty, fresh object, making sure the `dto` variable holds the merged result. The rest of your function can then safely assume a fully populated input variable.

The **third** and final option I'll mention is a remix of [QBM5's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35138094/419956), but I agree with the commenter's there that [if you *can* use a `pureComputed`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30316954/419956) (which, in your example, is perfectly fine), you probably should:

```
function ViewModel(data)  {
  var self = this;
  data = data || {};
  this.Filename = ko.observable(data.Filename);
  this.FilenameText = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.Filename() || "";
  });
}
```

---

PS. You didn't have the underlying issue you mention because you spell `FileName` and `Filename` with different capitalization on `this` and `data` respectively, didn't you? ;-)

Comment: No, no underlying issue that I'm aware of. The data comes in as data.Filename and I use this(self).FileName as the observable - doesn't really do anything. I've done it for a bunch of other things and it doesn't seem to matter.