# Referencing observable from inline computed method

Tags: knockout.js

Am I missing anything, or is it simply not possible to declare a computed "inline" property like `id_and_name` below in my first example?

```
function viewmodel(){

    var self = this;

    // adding 'inline' won't work (exception that the functions doesn't exist):
    self.person = ko.observable({
        id: ko.observable(),
        name: ko.observable(),
        id_and_name: ko.computed(function(){ return this.id() + this.name(); }, self.person)
    });

    // this works:
    self.person.id_and_name = ko.computed(function(){ 
        return this.id() + this.name(); 
    }, self.person);
}
```

Comment: What version of knockout are you using?  You could try id_and_name: ko.pureComputed(function(){ return this.person.id() + this.person.name(); }, self)

Comment: @Jonathan I'm using the latest version. But as far as I can tell, this issue is more related to how javascript handles things, rather than knockout? But I will give it a try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `self.person` is undefined until *after* the `ko.observable` call has returned. The `computed` is bootstrapped *before* that, so it is bootstrapped at a moment when `self.person` is still `undefined`. You can check it out in [the `computed` source code file](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/dependentObservable.js), pretty easy to read actually.

Here's one way to look at that:

```
function viewmodel() {
  var self = this;

  self.person = "temp";

  self.person = ko.observable({
    id: ko.observable(),
    name: ko.observable(),
    id_and_name: ko.computed(function() {
      console.log(this);
      return this.id() + this.name();
    }, self.person)
  });
}
```

It'll log `"temp"` upon initializing, because that's what `self.person` *is* at that time. You cannot change the `this` target for the computed read function after it was created.

So nope, what you want can't be done. You need your second solution or a proper view model constructor function*.

---

* Your top level `viewmodel` is already such a constructor function. You could create an inner constructor funciton `person` with `id` and `name` properties, and `new` that up, give it a `id_and_name` computed that will automatically have the correct `this` bound.

Comment: Thank you. What about `ko.pureComputed` which is mentioned in the comments?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "proper" view model constructor function? This is the function in question, so can you please elaborate "proper"? :)

Comment: I've added a footnote explaining my constructor function suggestion. (Also, `pureComputed` has no effect on this problem whatsoever, see (e.g.) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30317890/419956)).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks again for all your help! Related question, is it valid to add an instance of a function to an observable, e.g. `self.person = ko.observable(new person())`?

Comment: Most definitely. That's exactly how I'd do it. Have you checked out [the Knockout tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) yet? They're short, to the point, and explain all this pretty well.

Comment: Yeah I've skimmed through them but obviously missed that part :) Thanks